# Extract artist gender with Spotipy

Tags: spotify, spotipy

Is there a way to extract artist gender from Spotify track data using Spotipy? I have looked through both the Spotify and Spotipy documentation and have not been able to find anything about artist gender. However, I have seen some analyses of artist gender online and am hoping to be able to extract the gender through Spotipy along with all of the track attributes data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not from Spotify, but you can try via [MusicBrainz](https://musicbrainz.org), they have gender information (see e.g. Lorde's screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That did the job. Thank you for the reco!